# What's the difference between these two selectors in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have these two selectors and I want to know the difference between both of them:

```
$("table#tabla_semiter > tbody > tr").eq(indiceSemiter).after(html1);
```

AND

```
$("table#tabla_semiter tbody tr").eq(indiceSemiter).after(html1);
```

Thanks

Comment: immediate child vs descendant. Would make a difference, if you nest tables, for example.

Answer (score 1):

> The child combinator (E > F) can be thought of as a more specific form of the descendant combinator (E F) in that it selects only first-level descendants.

Taken from https://api.jquery.com/child-selector/

Answer (score 0):

The documentation would yield the answer.

> element element   div p   Selects all `<p>` elements inside  elements
>
> element`>`element div `>` p   Selects all `<p>` elements where the parent is a  element

Answer (score 0):

div p Selects all `<p>` elements inside div

div > p Selects all `<p>` elements where the parent is a div

the first Selector

select Exactly tr then child of table#tabla_semiter > tbody >

and Second Selector 
 get All tr in tbody

for more Detail see this Sample

```
    <body>
  <table id="tbl">
       <tbody>
           <tr>
               <td> First Row</td>
           </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Second Row</td>
                <td>
                    <table>
                       <tbody>
                           <tr>
                               <td>First Child</td>
                           </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>    

           </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
</body>

   $("#tbl tbody tr td").css("background-color","blue");
   $("#tbl>tbody>tr>td").css("background-color","red");
```

[Sample](https://jsfiddle.net/bxkxjew1/3/)